# Cisco Packet Tracer didn't run after install in Debian 32bit

Tags: linux, debian

I have install Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1 on Debian Wheezy x86(32bit).
But when I start, Packet Tracer didn't run.
When I try start through terminal "/usr/local/PacketTracer6/packettracer", then appear message 'Starting Packet Tracer 6.0.1' and didn't run too.
Did I make mistake?

BTW, I install like this:

```
chmod -x CiscoPacketTracer

./CiscoPacketTracer
```

Thanks for your attention :D

Answer (score 0):

You must have the libc6 version 2.15..

i have Cruchbang with the same repos of Debian Wheezy and the version is 2.13 you have to update to that version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly similar output. I had installed it using normal user. Installing it via super user worked. Also I changed the installation directory to be `/opt/pt` (which is default if you don't specify otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

run this command "sudo apt install libqt5xml5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5script5"

you can read tutorial in my article [How to Fix Packettracer 7.11 Not Start Ubuntu 18.04](https://rafibanget.blogspot.co.id/2018/05/how-to-fix-packettracer-711-not-start.html)